# How to find "page" number for a comment in a paginated comment system?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a comment system with pagination, 10 per page. I want to make permalinks to the comments. I'd like to be able to have the script figure out what page the comment is on without having to specify the page number and without excessively large queries or processing. So, for example, a link to a comment on page 5 would open the browser on comment page 5 and #scrolled to the comment (as opposed to showing the comment on it's own page).

I had thought to use 2 mysql queries, one SELECT all CommentId and then php `array_search` to find the position in the result and from that I could calculate what page it would be on.  A 2nd query would get the page of comments required. This seems quite inefficient though especially if there are a lot of comments Ids to pull.

Could anyone suggest a simpler or more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can all be done pretty easily with SQL, assuming that `comment_id` is some form of auto-incrementing number, this should return the exact page:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*)/$comments_per_page) FROM COMMENTS 
   WHERE ENTRY_ID = $entry_id AND comment_id < $comment_id;
```

Of course, this assumes "flat comments" (no parent-child relationships). Obviously, `$comments_per_page` is the number of comments which are shown on each page (this may just be a constant), `$entry_id` refers to the blog/forum post which the comment was made under and the `$comment_id` is the comment you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks both for the answers :)

Answer (score 3):

Well if you know the # of comments per page and that doesn't change, you should be able to count from MySQL.  If you're browser perma-link has the comment_id in it, would be something like:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    comments c
where
    comment_id < $comment_id
and
    topic_id = $topic_id -- or whatever
```

Then with this number in PHP, you would be able to calculate which page to lookup and display on the database.